# how to solve a system of equations with inexact coefficients

Tags: equation-solving

I going to ask my question in another way, and excuse me for my English. My question is

```
  H1[x_, y_]=(d x + w y) + 2(c x - a y)/d + y^2 a^2
```

I need to chose values for those five parameters for some reason, then, for example, I choose them like

```
S1 = {b -> -1.2, c -> 0.1, d -> 4, a -> - 0.8, w -> 2}
```

When I try to search for the intersection values of `H1` with the `y` axis

```
Solve[(H1[0, y] /. S1) == -0.5, y]
 (*{{y -> -3.52859}, {y -> -0.221405}}*)

y1 = -3.5285945694153686;
y2 = -0.22140543058463089;
Solve[(H1[0, y] /. S1) == -1, y]
(*{{y -> -3.27254}, {y -> -0.477458}}*)

 y3 = -3.272542485937368;
 y4 = -0.4774575140626314;
```

now I have

```
H2[x_, y_] = (-1 + 4 (c1 + b1 y)^2 - 2 (1 + x α1 + γ1)^3 + a1 x + y β1)/(c1 + b1 y)^3
```

another function with six new parameters, i need to find these parameters by solving the system

```
eq1 = Numerator[Factor[H2[0, y1] - H2[0, y2]]]
eq2 = Numerator[Factor[H2[0, y3] - H2[0, y4]]]
```

This system is with inexact parameters

```
Sol = Solve[({eq1, eq2} /. {b1 -> 1, γ1 -> 0.5}) == 0, {β1, c1}, Reals]
```

When i use `Solve`, it's giving me a solution of the same system but with inexact coefficients. My problem is when I try to solve this system

```
e1=H1[0, y]-H1[0, Y]
e2=H2[0, y]-H2[0, Y]
```

I need to find the same results of `y1`, `y2`, `y3` and `y4`, but since `Solve` uses exact parameters, I don't find the same results. I need a solution, please, thank you.

Comment: I reformatted your post, please, check it.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Before substituting values you should derive the equation symbollically:

```
H1[x_, y_] := (d x + w y) + 2 (c x - a y)/d + y^2 a^2
```

Evaluate the intersection `x==0,y==ya`

```
sol1[ya_] := y /. Solve[ya == H1[0, y], y]


H2[x_, y_] := (-1 + 4 (c1 + b1 y)^2 -2 (1 + x \[Alpha]1 + \[Gamma]1)^3 + a1 x +y \[Beta]1)/(c1 + b1 y)^3
```

Set of equations

```
eqn = {Numerator[Factor[H2[0, sol1[-1/2][[1]]] - H2[0, sol1[-1/2][[2]]]]],
Numerator[Factor[H2[0, sol1[-1 ][[1]]] - H2[0,sol1[-1 ][[2]]]]]};
```

Solve for special parameters:

```
subst = {b -> -1.2, c -> 0.1, d -> 4, a -> -0.8,w -> 2,b1 -> 1, \[Gamma]1 -> 0.5}
NSolve[eqn /. subst, {c1, \[Beta]1}, Reals]
(*{{c1 -> 1.07508, \[Beta]1 -> -11.2073}, 
{c1 -> -1.54514, \[Beta]1 ->9.84792}, 
{c1 -> 3.71031, \[Beta]1 -> -2.16057}}*)
```

Hope it helps!